# How would I evaluate the convergence of the following limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}(n^{2\alpha}+1)}}$$

For what values of $\alpha$ does this series converge? How would I evaluate this limit, I have tried d'Alembert's criterion but it was inconclusive. How else could I approach this series?

(I made an edit since I made a mistake with the degree of the root. My apologies)

Comment: what other tests or criteria do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $\alpha$ cannot be $0$. See that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}(n^{2\alpha}+1)}}=
\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}}\sqrt{1+n^{-2\alpha}}}
$$
and $\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}\geq 2$ for all $\alpha\gt0$, so by comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ the series is convergent for all $\alpha\gt0$.

Now for $\alpha\lt 0$ write $\beta=-\alpha$. Then,

$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}}\sqrt{1+n^{-2\alpha}}}=
\frac{n^{\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}}}{n^{\beta}\sqrt{n^{-2\beta}+1}}=
\frac{n^{\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\sqrt{n^{-2\beta}+1}}\geq \frac{n^{\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\sqrt{2}}\to\infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$ so we cannot have convergence.

Thus there is only convergence for $\alpha\gt0$.

Comment: What about when $\alpha$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$? (I made a mistake with the degree of the root)

Comment: In that case we have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{n^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}(n^{2\alpha}+1)}}=
\frac{1}{n^{\frac{2\alpha}{5}+\frac{2}{5\alpha}}\sqrt[5]{1+n^{-2\alpha}}}
$$ so you need to consider the behaviour of $\frac{2\alpha}{5}+\frac{2}{5\alpha}$. If it is $\gt 1$, we can use the p-series test to show it converges. If it is between $0$ and $1$ it diverges by p-series test. The case for negative $\alpha$ is much the same as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} (n^{2\alpha} +1 )}}\leq\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \cdot n^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{n^{\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\leq\frac{1}{n^2} $$
for $\alpha >0.$

If $\alpha <0 $ then $$a_n> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\to \infty$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with the degree of the root. How would you evaluate the expression now?